# Python iterative Button Counter

Tags: python, variables, for-loop

my current code is used to build gym routines. I am currently building a feature to delete exercises. To do this I have created a widget at the side of each exercise which when clicked should delete that exercise. I have created these widgets using a for loop and have created a variable called `Counter` which is assigned the number of exercises. This widget is then linked to a function which should delete the exercise. My problem is that whatever button I click on the counter is the same, which is the max value. This is the current code:

```
    Count = -1
    Count4 = 0
    for item in Sets_ID:
        Count = Count + 1
        if RoutinesCount == 0:            
            self.Delete = Button(self.FrameRoutine, bg = "PaleTurquoise1", font =("Arial","16"), text = "X", command = self.DeleteExercise)
            self.Delete.grid(row = 5+Count, column = 5)
        else:
            Count4 = Count4 + 2
            self.Delete2 = Button(self.FrameRoutine, bg = "PaleTurquoise1", font =("Arial","16"), text = "X", command = self.DeleteExercise)
            self.Delete2.grid(row = 8 + Count + Count4, column = 5)


def DeleteExercise(self):
    global Count  

    print (Count)
```

My problem is that the counter always has the max value as it is incremented in the for loop with the widget. I do not know how to assign counter the number of the widget.

Comment: Please provide more code or more details. What is Count4? why using `global`? you can use variables from outer scopes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have variables and scopes issue. Simply declare the counter at an outer variable scope, and reset it in your `DeleteExercise` function. If you use a class, save it as attribute.

```
class MYBigWidget():
    def __init__(self):
        self.Count = -1
        self.Count4 = 0

    def Buildier():
        for item in Sets_ID:
            self.Count = self.Count + 1
            if RoutinesCount == 0:            
                self.Delete = Button(self.FrameRoutine, bg = "PaleTurquoise1", font =("Arial","16"), text = "X", command = self.DeleteExercise)
                self.Delete.grid(row = 5+Count, column = 5)
            else:
                self.Count4 = self.Count4 + 2
                self.Delete2 = Button(self.FrameRoutine, bg =    "PaleTurquoise1", font =("Arial","16"), text = "X", command =    self.DeleteExercise)
                self.Delete2.grid(row = 8 + self.Count + self.Count4, column = 5)


    def DeleteExercise(self):
        print self.Count
```